# Angular JS, Select Click not invoked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

Well I don't have any idea why it's not working on Chrome and it's working on FireFox

**SelectModel**

```
selectModel: [
                        {
                            value: "asc", htmlText : "A-Z", selected: ""
                        },
                        {
                            value: "desc", htmlText : "Z-A", selected: ""
                        },
                        {
                            value: "startDate", htmlText : "Date", selected: ""
                        }
                    ]
```

## html

```
<option ng-click="sortContent(item)" ng-selected="item.selected" class="sort_option" value="{{item.value}}" ng-repeat="item in selectModel">
        {{item.htmlText}}
</option>
```

=========================================================================
**Directive**:

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
    scope.sortContent =  function(item_){
            console.info("???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????")
        }
}
```

The problem is that the function is not invoking on googleChrome,

You can try this here:
Works on FFox, doesn't on Chrome *_*
https://jsfiddle.net/bt6hmbvf/1/

Comment: It's maybe just a typo here, but you have a different name in your controller's list and in your `ng-repeat`

Comment: Can you post full code or a JS fiddle. Some parts are not clear.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I copied wrong part :P but that's not a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is simple. `Ng-click` doesn't work in `<option>`. It works in `<select>`. I had similar issue two days ago.

I have updated the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/bt6hmbvf/5/).

Comment: Yeah but then, the "item" is undefinied

Comment: You cannot send item like that. Use ng-model in select.

Comment: Updating link in answer.

Comment: Yeah, your answer is the solution for my problem, thank you very much : )

Comment: @AngularHarsh is right but i think for options ng-change is good practice

Comment: No problem. 
@Keval: Yes ng-change is also good and what I used in my problem statement but ng-change is expensive.. also OP used ng-click :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-app ="myApp" it will work this solution is for your given fiddle

Your example with error : http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/bt6hmbvf/

see this examle: https://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/bt6hmbvf/4/

```
<div ng-app ="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        {{d}}
</div>
```

---

**Edit:**

see this example: https://jsfiddle.net/hk0tn0co/3/

Now in your new edited fiddle you have to apply ng-change to select not to  option and as when you use ng-chnage then it requires mg-model also

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <sampdir>
        {{msgClick}}
        <select ng-change="sortContent(item.value)" ng-model="item.value">
           <option  ng-selected="item.value" class="sort_option" value="{{item.value}}" ng-repeat="item in selectModel" >
                        {{item.htmlText}}
                    </option>
                </select>        
    </sampdir>
</div>
```